# Android Handler Message Queue

Tags: android, handler

I am calling

handler.postDelayed(runnable, time);
handler.post(runnable2);

Will the second runnable not get handled until the first message in the queue does, after "time" has passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The second runnable will be posted immediately and would execute before the first -- depending on the `time` parameter in the first, anyway. If you post the first with a negligible delay for `time` it's *possible* it could execute first. I don't believe there's any guarantee in place that it wouldn't.